# How to tell STDIN to stop reading?

Tags: ruby

So I am studying Build Awesome Command-Line Applications in Ruby. On page 81, we're supposed to use STDIN to enter more than one task into a project.

```
 File.open(global_options[:filename], 'a+') do |todo_file|
  if task_names.empty?
    puts "Reading new tasks from stdin..."
    task_names = STDIN.readlines.map {|a| a.chomp}
  end
  tasks = 0
  task_names.each do |task|
    todo_file.puts [task, Time.now].join(', ')
    tasks+=1
  end
  if tasks == 0
    raise "You must provide tasks on the command-line or standard input"
  end
end
```

The usual way to enter tasks into a project it's like this `$todo new "Rake leaves` but with the code above we can to what's in the example below.

It does work. But how do I tell STDIN to stop listening? The example on how to use it is this...

```
$ todo new
Rake leaves
Take out trash
Clean garage
Put away dishes
^D
```

What does the `^D` represent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s an [end-of-file character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file). You can type this literally on Unix systems with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or on Windows with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. The traditional way of displaying the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> modifier is with a `^` prefix, e.g., `^D`.

Be aware that this closes standard input entirely. If you want to read more data after entering these lines, you’ll need to check the input itself for a different delimiter—for instance, an empty line.

Answer (score 4):

You can close STDIN by pressing Ctrl-d on Unix-like systems or Ctrl-z on Windows.

> What does the ^6 represent?

Are you sure it says `^6` and not `^d`? If so, that's probably a typo.